# Unable install own google chrome extension

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome-extension

i want to host my own extension on my asp.net server (it's free web server, so i don't have access to machine.config etc.). 
But the point of my problem is here. I put the packaged extension to server and i want use something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = Request.QueryString["f"];
        if (file != null)
        {            
            Response.Write("");
            if (file == "0")
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/x-chrome-extension";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=RemotePlay_extension.crx");
                Response.TransmitFile("~/Extensions/Update/RemotePlay_extension.crx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/x-chrome-extension";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=RemotePlay_extension.crx");
                Response.TransmitFile("~/Extensions/RemotePlay_extension.crx");
            }
        }
    }
```

But every time I get this error:
[image: Error i get after download the extension: Package is invalid: 'CRX_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED']

Source of extension manifest:

```
{
 "name": "Remote Play",
 "description": "DJ interface to use RP.",
 "version": "0.0.0.2",
 "update_url": "../Extensions/RemoteChrome_Update.xml",
 "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*"],
 "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
 "content_scripts": [{"matches": ["http://*/*"],"js": ["inject.js"]}],
 "page_action": {"default_icon": "playico.png", "default_popup": "popup.html"},
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Where is that error?

Answer (score 1):

You can not trigger installation through `Page_Load` function and headers

- You should have a link tag `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item"
  href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf">`
- You can trigger installation through `chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)`

For more information check [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation).